# Using L'Hopital to find $\lim_{x→∞} ( \ln \sqrt[3]{4x^3-4x^2+5} - \ln \sqrt[3]{2x^3-5x+4} )$

Tags: calculus, limits, radicals

I've been trying to do it and I still haven't been able to, I don't know what problem I have but it gives me 1, instead when I put it through some application it gives me the result of $ /1/2 * ln(2)$
I'm sorry if the result doesn't look good, I don't know how to use it.
I am going to give you the process that I have done and there is the limit
thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: $\ln p-\ln q= \ln(p/q)$ and not $\frac{\ln p}{\ln q}$

Comment: Are you talking about the first part?

Comment: The very first step, yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \ln((4x^3-4x^2+5)^{1/3})-\ln((2x^3-5x+4)^{1/3})$$

Now use that $\ln(a)-\ln(b)=\ln\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)$

$$=\lim_{x \to  \infty} \ln\left(\frac{(4x^3-4x^2+5)^{1/3}}{(2x^3-5x+4)^{1/3}}\right)=\lim_{x \to  \infty} \ln\left(\left(\frac{4x^3-4x^2+5}{2x^3-5x+4}\right)^{1/3}\right)$$

Next use $\ln(a^x)=x\cdot \ln(a)$

$$=\lim_{x \to  \infty} \frac13\cdot \ln\left(\frac{4x^3-4x^2+5}{2x^3-5x+4}\right)$$

Finally expand the fraction by $\frac1{x^3}$ or you use L´Hospital. At this method you differentiate the numerator and the denominator three times.

Comment: I don't understand the last part, do I do it like I was doing in the third step?

Comment: Do you know the rule $\ln(a^x)=x\ln(a)$? Or do you mean the expansion?

Comment: no i think i haven't seen it

Comment: This is one of the logarithm rules, for instance [here](http://www.statistica.com.au/logarithm_rules.html). But there are many other sources.

Comment: @Seis I think you need to review the basic [properties of logarithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities#Using_simpler_operations). You need to be comfortable with them if you are going to do calculus with logarithms.

Comment: Sorry, the part I don't understand is how I can use the LHopital in the last part

Comment: You differentiate the numerator and the denominator of $\left(\frac{4x^3-4x^2+5}{2x^3-5x+4}\right)$ which is $\frac{12x^2-8x}{6x^2-5}$. This is not sufficient. So you differentiate again. $\left(\frac{12x^2-8x}{6x^2-5}\right)\rightarrow \frac{24x-8}{12x}$ And again. What is $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \frac{24}{12}=\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} 2$?

Comment: thanks, i got it

Comment: There is also the intermediate step of bringing the limit inside the ln. You are allowed to do this because ln is a continuous function for positive values.

Comment: @Seis That pleases me. You´re welcome. Please accept one of the answers ($\checkmark$).

Answer (score 3):

As @DatBoi points out, we can get the result without needing to use L'Hopital.  I get $\frac{\ln2}{3}$, since $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{4x^3-4x^2+5}{2x^3-5x+4}\to2$$

Comment: Yes, but I have to do the exercise by that method, that's the problem I have

Comment: You could do the limit I indicated by using L'Hopital.  The one within the logarithm.

Comment: Apply it three times, to get $24/12=2$.

Comment: I'm trying to do it but I can't understand it, could you explain me a little better please? sorry.

Comment: The numerator and denominator both go to infinity, so you can apply L'Hopital.  Actually you can apply it repeatedly.  Do you know how to differentiate a polynomial?

Comment: of course, what I don't understand is how I can apply it three times as you say

Comment: Well, after the first application, you have $(12x^2-8x)/(6x^2-5)$.  Numerator and denominator go to infinity again, so you can apply it again...

Comment: You might as well add this l'Hôpital stuff to your answer, rather than burying it down here in the comments. OTOH, I fully agree that using l'Hôpital for this limit is overkill, but hey, it's just a homework exercise...